# How to implements interface on class?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

I have a custom class called Greeter. 
It has a method called `fromJson` that takes an object  as parameter and assign all properties of that object to the class.
I used an interface called GreeterInterface to do type checking for both the class and the object parameter.

```
interface GreeterInterface { 
    greeting: string;
    name: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number; 
}
class Greeter implements GreeterInterface{
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    fromJson(obj: object) { 
        Object.assign(this, obj)
        return this;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let param: GreeterInterface = {
    greeting: 'hello',
    lastname: 'hina',
    name: 'love',
    age:1
}
let greeter = new Greeter('hola').fromJson(param);


let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say: ";
button.onclick = function() {
    console.log(greeter)
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

This does not compile. It says that Greeter has not property greeting.

Comment: I would agree with the compiler. One must *declare* properties in TypeScript as it is *statically typed*. Check out the definition of the class in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html and note the extra line (declaring that the class has the specified `greeter` property) at the top of the `Greeter` class..

Answer (score 1):

**An interface only defines the shape of the data that it applies to, it does not define the implementation.** Though you are telling TypeScript that `Greeter` has the shape of a `GreeterInterface` you are still not telling TypeScript how the shape is implemented. A single shape can be implemented in a number of ways, and TS makes no assumptions as to what it is you want for the implementation. Here's an example:

```
interface GreeterInterface { 
    greeting: string;
    name: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number; 
}

class Greeter implements GreeterInterface{
    greeting: "Hola" | "Hello";
    name: string;
    lastname: string;

    private _age: number;

    get age(): number {
        return this._age;
    }

    set age(value: number) {
        this._age = value;
    }

    constructor(message: "Hola" | "Hello") {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    fromJson(obj: object) { 
        Object.assign(this, obj)
        return this;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

The shape specified by `GreeterInterface` suggests that the `greeting` field should be a `string`, but `Greeter` implemented it with a narrower type, which is perfectly valid. Similarly, `age` could just be a field, but `Greeter` implements it as a getter/setter, which is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I changed the constructor to `constructor(obj: GreeterInterface)`  instead of fromJson because with Louis solution, TypeScript complain “has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor”

```
interface GreeterInterface {
    greeting: string;
    name: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number;
}

class Greeter implements GreeterInterface{

    age: number;
    greeting: string;
    lastname: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(obj: GreeterInterface) {
        this.lastname =  obj.lastname;
        this.greeting =  obj.greeting;
        this.name =  obj.name;
        this.age =  obj.age;
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let param: GreeterInterface = {
    greeting: 'hello',
    lastname: 'hina',
    name: 'love',
    age:1
}
let greeter = new Greeter(param);


let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say: ";
button.onclick = function() {
    console.log(greeter)
}

document.body.appendChild(button)
```